# Access variables from parent in nested asynchronous calls

Tags: node.js, scope

I'm having trouble figuring out why I can't access a variable from a child call. I previously had this code in a standalone function and it worked, but since moving it to the main thread of my websocket it does not.

The problem is that `auth_session` is accessible in the first query scope, but for some reason not in the second even though it is a child.

```
 mysqlconn.query('SELECT * FROM auth_sessions WHERE session_id = ? AND session_name = ? AND (expires > ? OR expires = 0) LIMIT 1', [cookies.SESSION_ID, cookies.SESSION_NAME, time()], function(err, results, fields) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
    if (results.length == 1) {
      var auth_session = results[0];
      if (md5(request.httpRequest.headers['user-agent'] + (request.httpRequest.headers['accept-encoding'] + request.httpRequest.headers['accept-language'])) == auth_session.fingerprint) {
        mysqlconn.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1', [auth_session.uid], function(err, results, fields) { // auth_session is defined here (I have checked using console.log() too)
          if (err) { throw err; }
          if (results.length === 1) {
            var userinfo = results[0];
            if (auth_session.session === 1) { // throws: TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined     
              mysqlconn.query('UPDATE auth_sessions SET expires = ? WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1', [time() + SESSION_TIMEOUT, auth_session.id]);
            }
            // do some stuff with variables inside of userinfo
          } else { reject_request(); }
        });
      } else { reject_request(); }
    } else { reject_request(); }
  });
}
```

Comment: We don't see the full function. Is it possible you use auth_session somewhere else in the same function?

Comment: @NineBerry, no it is not used anywhere else. I tried removing the preceeding `var` and defining `auth_session` as a global variable before both functions are called. But that didn't work either.

Comment: Using a global variable would actually make things worse. Have you tried using let instead of var?

Comment: I get this error when using `let`: `SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode`

Comment: @NineBerry, actually it turns out your first comment was right on the money. Further along in the `// do some stuff` section I had defined `var auth_session = ....` and that was causing the inner query scope to not inherit auth_session at all.

Comment: you should use let to make sure the variable is not global to the function. Otherwise there can be unexpected side effects when there are multiple code paths in the function being executed in parallel. Enable strict mode in node.js for that.

Comment: @NineBerry, I can't use `let` without `use strict` and I don't want to use strict mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Credit for this answer should go to @NineBerry, but no answer was posted outside of comments.*

The problem was that inside of the inner most loop, there was a declaration hiding  somewhere with `var auth_session = ...`. This meant that the variable `auth_session` was never inherited to begin with by that loop, and was therefore undefined until it's definition inside of the loop.

By removing the `var` the inner most function then inherited the variable, and was therefore able to access and change it in the larger scope.